# Use rexexp in check constraint Mysql

Tags: mysql, check-constraints

I want to add a check constraint on the primary key of the `accomodatie` table named `code`. This code has to start with 4 letters and end with 4 numbers (Abcd0123). I thought I could use a regexp for that in a check constraint like below:

```
alter table accomodatie add constraint check (
accomodatie.code regexp '/^[A-Z][a-z]{3}\d{4}$/' 
);
```

But when I want to execute the statement above I get an error:

```
Error Code: 3819. Check constraint 'accomodatie_chk_1' is violated.
```

I have also tried like instead of regexp but that does not do the trick.

Comment: I tested this on MySQL 8.0 and it works fine. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return for you?

Comment: @BillKarwin 8.0.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I tested further and there are a few issues.

Don't use `/<regexp>/`. Using the slashes is borrowed from PHP or Perl, but MySQL doesn't use that. Get rid of the slashes.

The `\d` sequence is not supported. That's also borrowed from PHP or some other language. Use `[[:digit:]]` as a sequence that matches digits. Or good old `[0-9]`.

```
mysql> select 'Abcd0123' regexp '^[A-Z][a-z]{3}[[:digit:]]{4}$' as regexp_match;
+--------------+
| regexp_match |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

Also keep in mind the default collation in your session is probably case-insensitive, so there's no difference between `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`.

```
mysql> select 'abcd0123' regexp '^[A-Z][a-z]{3}[[:digit:]]{4}$' as regexp_match;
+--------------+
| regexp_match |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

But you can use a case-sensitive collation if you want case mismatches to result in a regexp non-match:

```
mysql> select 'abcd0123' regexp '^[A-Z][a-z]{3}[[:digit:]]{4}$' collate utf8mb3_bin as regexp_match;
+--------------+
| regexp_match |
+--------------+
|            0 |
+--------------+
```

Review the documentation for MySQL's regular expression syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax

Comment: Thanks for helping Bill, great explanation!